# Update xml database if newer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Good day, I've this application that read 7 small xml and store the result but since now it download everything even when the xml files are unchanged.

I'd love to check if the xml is newer or it has been modified but I can't find a solution, maybe it's a simple one and I'm trying to achieve this in the harder way

Could anyone help?

Thanks’ in advice :)

Here's my ATM code:

```
WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
downloader.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://feeds.feedburner.com/bluey/eventi20" + "?" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(EventiDownloaded);
```

I've tried looking for lastmodify, or something I could use, in the header of the xml in this way

```
WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
downloader.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://feeds.feedburner.com/bluey/eventi20" + "?" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(EventiDownloaded);
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = downloader.ResponseHeaders;
 foreach(var x in myWebHeaderCollection)
   for (int i = 0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)
      MessageBox.Show("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.AllKeys.GetEnumerator() + " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.AllKeys.ElementAt(i));
```

But I get a null reference error in myWebHeaderCollection

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use ETag http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

You could request only headers (not the whole content) and grab the ETag and save the value. So you should only do full request when the ETag changes. I haven't done this personally. I had the same problem as you but my feed is updated once a week, so I did a bit of workaround that doesn't involve this implementation.

Anyway, this is a quick sample to demonstrate the header only request and you should see ETag and you can extract the value for your usage.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.forexfactory.com/ffcal_week_this.xml");

    // Only request the headers, not the whole content
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    var response = webRequest.GetResponse();

    for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.Keys[i] + " : " + response.Headers[i]);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I'll try this code ASAP and I'll let you know if it work :)