# How To Check Whether A URL Is Valid?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to be able to check whether a specified URL is valid [Preferably both Active and Well Formed],

eg

```
//invalid
http://fdsafsd.com/
//valid
http://google.com/
```

Is it possible? I was using the codes specified on other posts in stackoverflow but they all don't seem to work. This is one of the examples.

```
private bool checkWebsite(string url){
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse webResponse;
    try{
        //System.Net.WebRequest does not contain a definition for GetResponse();
        webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "valid". Merely well-formed? Or actively not returning an HTTP error?

Comment: Why do you think google.co is invalid?! **It's 100% valid URL!**

Comment: @Cairnarvon Well formed and active if possible. I've updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I don't know what happened but when i visit the link http://google.co/ just now, i got an Error 503, now i got diverted to http://google.com/. I've just updated with an invalid link. Thanks!

Comment: @Jieqin best way is probably to use Regex to check whether it is in a valid format, so you don't have to make a request to the server. If it is in a valid format, the send a request to server (just request the head and check if the response is not 404). I will try to get the code when I get home. Meanwhile, you can check my sample here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700303/update-xml-databse-if-newer/15722342#15722342 You need to modify it so you can grab the  first line - something like this `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Not the most elegance code though.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var uriName = "http://www.google.com";
    Uri uriResult;

    bool isUriValid = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;

    if (isUriValid)
    {
        var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriResult);
        // Only request the headers, not the whole content
        webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            // Exception is thrown if 404
            var response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            // Check if status return is 200 OK, then active. You might want to check the HttpStatusCode for others
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }  
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Url is not valid");
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but the variable 'webRequest' didn't have a method 'GetResponse()'.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe it is not supported for WP8. Ill get back to you in few hours after work. But in the meantime you can check the 'HttpClient` class or `WebClient`. `HttpClient` is the latest lib from MS. But the idea to implement this remain the same. Send a request to get the header and check the response code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with a HttpClient ( You should add using System.Net.Http;) :

```
    private async Task<bool> IsURLAvailable(Uri url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        try
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return true;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```